# binding to a property of an object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I want to **bind** a **series of TextBoxes** in a grid into **properties of an object** which is itself another property in my ViewModel (the DataContext).

`CurrentPerson` consists of `Name` and `Age` properties

**Inside the ViewModel:**

```
public Person CurrentPerson { get; set ... (with OnPropertyChanged)}
```

Xaml :

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" >
<TextBox Text="{Binding Age}" >
```

I wasn't sure on the approach to use, I set another DataContext in the grid scope, without any result, Also tried setting the source and path like Source=CurrentPerson, Path=Age again without any result, these were for trial and see if there would be any change or not.

How should I achieve this ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Does your `Person` class members `Name` and `Age` raise INPC themselves?

If you want to update the value of either `Name` or `Age` in the `ViewModel` and have it reflect in the view, you need them to raise property changed individually inside `Person` class as well.

The bindings are fine, but the view is not notified of changes from the view model. Also remember `UpdateSourceTrigger` for a `TextBox` by default is `LostFocus`, so setting that to `PropertyChanged` will update your string in the `ViewModel` as you're typing.

Simple example:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged {
  private string _name;
  public string Name {
    get {
      return _name;
    }

    set {
      if (value == _name)
        return;

      _name = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(() => Name);
    }
  }

  // Similarly for Age ...
}
```

Now your xaml would be:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding CurrentPerson}">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
  <TextBox Margin="15"
            Text="{Binding Age}" />
</StackPanel>
```

or you can also bind as suggested by @Kshitij:

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentPerson.Name}" />
  <TextBox Margin="15"
            Text="{Binding CurrentPerson.Age}" />
</StackPanel>
```

and to update view model as you're typing:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding CurrentPerson}">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
  <TextBox Margin="15"
            Text="{Binding Age, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 21):

Try this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentPerson.Name}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentPerson.Age}" />
```

Essentially, you can drill down into properties by using the `.` separator.

For future reference, if you want to drill down into collections, you can use `MyCollection[x]` just like you would in code (where x would be replaced by a hard-coded number, *not a variable*).

Comment: +1 and thanks for the info, weren't sure that in the Xaml part I can use this, but I think I tried this way too. Again did this approach with no result, CurrentPerson defined and trigger NotifyPropertyChanged but yet maybe there be something missing.

Comment: Seems that Notification changing won't take action this way. Is it true ? how should I fix this?

Comment: Make sure you create the object early enough (i.e. in the constructor)