# Binding background value in wpf datagrid cell

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a WPF app in VS2015. It's been developed as MVVM with nothing in the code-behind classes.

It has a user control containing a datagrid. I would like the background colour of any edited cell to be changed from white to red. I have a button bound to a method in the view model that applies the changed data to a database.

My problem is the binding of the *Background* property of the datagrid column.

My ViewModel contains:

```
private ObservableCollection<ComparisonRec> _piToAccessFilteredRecs;
```

The ComparisonRec implements *ClientEntityBase*

```
public class ComparisonRec : ClientEntityBase
```

This has an *IsDirty* property

I have the following *ValueConverter* class:

```
public class DirtyToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Brush ret;

            if ((bool)value == true)
            {
                ret = Brushes.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                ret = Brushes.White;
            } 

            return ret;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

The data context for my user control is set as follows:

```
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:CompareUCViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
```

In the DataGrid I have the binding:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding PiToAccessFilteredRecs}"
```

For the *DataGridTextColumn* that I need to highlight a change, I have the following binding:

```
Binding="{Binding Path=Access_Notes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
```

This works fine to display the data. To try and get the highlighting, I added the following:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Access_Notes.IsDirty, Converter={StaticResource DirtyToBrushConverter}}" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

It's not working :( I see the following in the output window for each row displayed:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsDirty' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=577941586)'. BindingExpression:Path=Access_Notes.IsDirty; DataItem='ComparisonRec' (HashCode=27207830); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Background' (type 'Brush')
```

Can anyone see where I went wrong please?

EDIT
As per @XAMIMAX suggestion, if I change binding to:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Access_Notes
```

The the string value of Access_Notes (the content that would be displayed in the grid cell) is passed to the value converter and an exception is thrown because this can't be cast to (bool)

Comment: Can you bind the entire `Access_Notes` and analyse it in your converter and see what you get?

Comment: What is Access_Notes?

Comment: Sorry, Acess_Notes is a public property of ComparisonRec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: [binding to a property of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610887/binding-to-a-property-of-an-object)

Because the DataGridTextColumn was already binding to Access_Notes this meant my setter just needed to bind to the IsDirty property as follows:

```
Value="{Binding IsDirty
```

For completeness, my working xaml is as follows:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="access_NotesColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="Access Notes" Binding="{Binding Path=Access_Notes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding IsDirty, Converter={StaticResource DirtyToBrushConverter}}" />
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>
```